# WORD VBA - Userform - Auto fill

Tags: vba, automation, ms-word, userform

I am trying to create a user form in VBA on Microsoft word. 
I have been following http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/create_employ_userform.html
to create the form.

I am very very very new to programming and have basically just been teaching myself as I go.

I get a "compile error: Sub of Function not defined" when I try and step through Call UF

I've attached the whole code for you to look at and tell me where I've gone wrong, happy for any suggestions.

Module - modMain

```
Option Explicit
Sub Autonew()
Create_Reset_Variables
Call UF
lbl_Exit:
Exit Sub
End Sub

Sub Create_Reset_Variables()
 With ActiveDocument.Variables
    .Item("varFormNumber").Value = " "
    .Item("varTitle").Value = " "
    .Item("varGivenName").Value = " "
    .Item("varFamilyName").Value = " "
    .Item("varStreet").Value = " "
    .Item("varSuburb").Value = " "
    .Item("varState ").Value = " "
    .Item("varPostCode").Value = " "
    .Item("varInterviewDate").Value = " "
  End With
  myUpdateFields
lbl_Exit:
  Exit Sub
End Sub



Sub myUpdateFields()
Dim oStyRng As Word.Range
Dim iLink As Long
 iLink = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.StoryType
 For Each oStyRng In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
  Do
    oStyRng.Fields.Update
    Set oStyRng = oStyRng.NextStoryRange
  Loop Until oStyRng Is Nothing
 Next
End Sub
```

Form - frmLetter13

```
Option Explicit
Public boolProceed As Boolean


Sub CalUF()
Dim oFrm As frmLetter13
Dim oVars As Word.Variables
Dim strTemp As String
Dim oRng As Word.Range
Dim i As Long
Dim strMultiSel As String
    Set oVars = ActiveDocument.Variables
    Set oFrm = New frmLetter13
    With oFrm
     .Show
     If .boolProceed Then
      oVars("varFormNumber").Value = TextBoxFormNumber
      oVars("varTitle").Value = ComboBoxTitle
      oVars("varGivenName").Value = TextBoxGivenName
      oVars("varFamilyName").Value = TextBoxFamilyName
      oVars("varStreet").Value = TextBoxStreet
      oVars("varSuburb").Value = TextBoxSuburb
      oVars("varState").Value = ComboBoxState
      oVars("varPostCode").Value = TextBoxPostCode
      oVars("varInterviewDate").Value = TextBoxInterviewDate
    End If
    Unload oFrm
    Set oFrm = Nothing
    Set oVars = Nothing
    Set oRng = Nothing
lbl_Exit
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Private Sub TextBoxFormNumber_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
    With ComboBoxTitle
        .AddItem "Mr"
        .AddItem "Mrs"
        .AddItem "Miss"
        .AddItem "Ms"
    End With
    With ComboBoxState
        .AddItem "QLD"
        .AddItem "NSW"
        .AddItem "ACT"
        .AddItem "VIC"
        .AddItem "TAS"
        .AddItem "SA"
        .AddItem "WA"
        .AddItem "NT"
    End With
lbl_Exit:
Exit Sub
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButtonCancel_Click()
Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButtonClear_Click()
Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButtonOk_Click()
    Select Case ""
    Case Me.TextBoxFormNumber
        MsgBox "Please enter the form number."
        Me.TextBoxFormNumber.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    Case Me.ComboBoxTitle
        MsgBox "Please enter the Applicant's title."
        Me.ComboBoxTitle.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    Case Me.TextBoxGivenName
        MsgBox "Please enter the Applicant's given name."
        Me.TextBoxGivenName.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    Case Me.TextBoxFamilyName
        MsgBox "Please enter the Applicant's family name."
        Me.TextBoxFamilyName.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    Case Me.TextBoxStreet
        MsgBox "Please enter the street address."
        Me.TextBoxStreet.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    Case Me.TextBoxSuburb
        MsgBox "Please enter the suburb."
        Me.TextBoxSuburb.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    Case Me.ComboBoxState
        MsgBox "Please enter the state."
        Me.ComboBoxState.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    Case Me.TextBoxPostCode
        MsgBox "Please enter the postcode."
        Me.TextBoxPostCode.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    Case Me.TextBoxInterviewDate
        MsgBox "Please enter the interview date."
        Me.TextBoxInterviewDate.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End Select
'Set value of a public variable declared at the form level.'
    Me.boolProceed = True
    Me.Hide
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.

The first issue is that you do not have a routine named UF for `Call UF` to call.

The routine that you have named `CalUF` should not be in the code for the UserForm but should be in modMain and renamed `CallUF`.

There is no need to include an exit point in your routine as you don't have an error handler.

Your AutoNew routine could be rewritten as:

```
Sub Autonew()
Create_Reset_Variables
CallUF
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the update - Whenever I step through the code I get a compile error on the 
'Create_Reset_Variables'

any suggestions ?

Comment: I don't get a compile error with the code that you posted.

Answer (score 1):

I have commented your `sub myUpdateFields` for you.

> Sub myUpdateFields()
>       Dim oStyRng As Word.Range
>       Dim iLink As Long
>
> ```
> iLink = ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.StoryType
> ' logically, iLink should be the StoryType of the first header in Section 1
> ' Why would this be needed in all StoryRanges?
> ' Anyway, it is never used. Why have it, then?
>
> ' This loops through all the StoryRanges
> For Each oStyRng In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
>
>     ' This also loops through all the StoryRanges
>     Do
>         oStyRng.Fields.Update
>         Set oStyRng = oStyRng.NextStoryRange
>     Loop Until oStyRng Is Nothing
>     'And after you have looped through all the StoryRanges
>
>     ' Here you go back and start all over again.
>  Next oStyRng End Sub
> ```

Frankly, I don't know if the Do loop does anything here. Perhaps it does. Read up about the `NextStoryRange` [property here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193730.aspx). I also don't know if using the same object variable in the inside loop upsets the outside loop. I don't know these things because I never needed to know them. Therefore I wonder why you need them on your second day in school.

You are setting a number of document variables. These could be linked to REF fields in your document which you wish to update. I bet your document has only one section, no footnotes and no textboxes with fields in them. Therefore I think that the following code should do all you need, if not more.

```
Sub myUpdateFields2()

    Dim Rng As Word.Range

    For Each Rng In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
        Rng.Fields.Update
     Next Rng
End Sub
```

To you, the huge advantage of this code is that you fully understand it. Towards this end I have avoiding using a name like oStyRng (presumably meant to mean "StoryRange Object"). It is true that a `Word.Range` is an object. It is also true that the procedure assigns a `StoryRange` type of `Range` to this variable. But the over-riding truth is that it is a `Word.Range` and therefore a `Range`. Code will be easier to read when you call a spade a spade, and not "metal object for digging earth". My preferred variable name for a `Word.Range` is, therefore, "Rng". But - just saying. By all means, use names for your variables which make reading your code easy for yourself.